# Python: Need help searching through a list for substring

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I know this is a simple question but I have a list full of hundreds of strings and I need help trying to select a few of them. For example, the list is:

```
lines = ["First Sentence dog", "Second Sentence dog", "Third Sentence cat", "Fourth Sentence cat"...]
```

I need to access and manipulate the indexes that contain the word "dog". The code I have so far is:

```
    for line in range(len(lines)):
        if "dog" in line:
            # Do some something
        elif "cat" in line:
            # Do some something else
        else:
            # Do other things
```

Thank you for any help!

Edit: The error I get is
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

To be specific, my question is: How can I retrieve and do something with the whole string by searching for a specific substring within it?

Comment: Great that you show your effort and the code you have so far! What is your question at this point, your post does not contain any... :) Note that `for line in range(len(lines))` will make `line` the index to iterate over whereas `for line in lines` will make `line` the actual strings. You might be interested in `enumerate` ;-)

Comment: you wanted `line` in `range(len(lines))` which is a sequence of integers. So `line` is an integer, not a string. Therefore `"dog"` can't be in it. You could catch this right away by putting `print(line)` at the top of the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i,line in enumerate(lines):
    if "dog" in line:
        # Do some something
    elif "cat" in line:
        # Do some something else
    else:
        # Do other things
```

`enumerate()` will allow you to iterate over an iterable, along with the index of the current element. If you don't need the the index, simply:

```
for line in lines:
    if "dog" in line:
        # Do some something
    elif "cat" in line:
        # Do some something else
    else:
        # Do other things
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use the index to access the string in the list.

```
for line in range(len(lines)):
    if "dog" in lines[line]:
        # Do some something
    elif "cat" in lines[line]:
        # Do some something else
    else:
        # Do other things
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try map() function.

First define the function where you can to do something:

```
def change(string):
     if string = 'dog':
         #do something
     else:
         #do something
```

Then try map() function. If you want output as list, then:

```
list(map(change,lines))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = [
    "First Sentence dog",
    "Second Sentence dog",
    "Third Sentence cat",
    "Fourth Sentence cat",
]


for index, line in enumerate(lines[:]):
    if "dog" in line:
        lines[index] = "Do Something"
    elif "cat" in line:
        lines[index] = "Do some something else"
    else:
        lines[index] = "Do other things"

print(lines)
```

### Output:

```
['Do Something', 'Do Something', 'Do some something else', 'Do some something else']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do something to the lines, then you could think about gathering all of them into a list first and then applying some function to them. One way could be as follows:

```
dog_strings = [x for x in lines if 'dog' in x]
```

Then you can apply a function to all the elements in this list as follows:

```
edited_dog_strings = map(some_function, dog_strings)
```

So now your code consists of two lines (and it might be more efficient than a for loop).